# Convert string in 1d array to 2d array with each character as seperate element

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have a data of type pandas.core.series.Series as follows:

```
print(x)

0  'School'
1  'Boy'
```

My aim is to convert it to something like (converted to 2d):

```
s1 = [ ['S']['c']['h']['o']['o']['l'],
       ['B']['o']['y']]
```

I tried various things like `np.reshape()` but using them I can only make it like:

```
[['School']
 ['Boy']]
```

I even tired `for i in x:` then converted to type list, then `np.reshape(len(i), 1)` to convert each string to 2d array. but I was not able to convert it to a form as in 's1'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try via `map()` and list comprehension:

```
x=x.map(lambda x:[[y] for y in list(x)]).astype(str).str.replace(', ','')
```

output of `x`:

```
0    [['S']['c']['h']['o']['o']['l']]
1                   [['B']['o']['y']]
dtype: object
```

Comment: Please also explain working of this statement. Specially "astype(str).str.replace(', ','')" part of code.

Comment: @AvijitSingh `x.map(lambda x:[[y] for y in list(x)])` part gives us a list of list like other answers then we are converting those to string via `astype()` method and finally replacing `', '` by  `''` empty character

Answer (score 0):

Calling `list` on a `str` will split it into a list of its characters:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = ["School", "Boy"])
df[0] = df[0].map(lambda x : [list(char) for char in list(x)])
```

Now, `df` is

```
                                0
0  [[S], [c], [h], [o], [o], [l]]
1                 [[B], [o], [y]]
```

If you don't want the dataframe and instead just want the `list` as in your question, you can either use `list(df[0])` as above, or

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = ["School", "Boy"])
result = [[list(char) for char in list(x)] for x in df[0]]
# [[['S'], ['c'], ['h'], ['o'], ['o'], ['l']], [['B'], ['o'], ['y']]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Best I can find at the moment

```
>>> df[0].str.extractall(r"(\w)").apply(list, axis=1).unstack().agg(lambda x: [i for i in x if pd.notnull(i)], axis=1)
0    [[S], [c], [h], [o], [o], [l]]
1                   [[B], [o], [y]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting from

```
[['School']
 ['Boy']]
```

, basic solution:

```
a = [['School'],['Boy']]
empty_lists = [ [] for _ in range(len(a)) ]
for i, word  in enumerate(a):
  for char in word[0]:
    empty_lists[i].append(char)
print(empty_lists)
```